# Owl carousel issue in safari

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

owl-item have width 0 automatically only at safari.. other browser have the width according to the screen!!..

here is my code

[image: 1]

Here is my html sample from firefox

```
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 4512px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 1000ms ease 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 376px;">
        <figure id="post-200" class="advertise development all portfolio-post portfolio-thumbnail">
            <div class="portfolio-thumbnail-container"></div>
            <figcaption class="thumbnail-caption text-center"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Here is my html sample from safari

```
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer">

<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; -webkit-transition-property: all; -webkit-transition-duration: 800ms; -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease; -webkit-transition-delay: initial; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); ">
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 0px;">
        <figure id="post-200" class="advertise development all portfolio-post portfolio-thumbnail">
            <div class="portfolio-thumbnail-container"></div>
            <figcaption class="thumbnail-caption text-center"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Anyone have the fix.

Comment: I see 99 errors in the console of the Safari browser,... Are they related to the Owl?